# Самый производительный и нетребовательный к железу вариант для веб-приложения

Tags: производительность, backend

## Что я имею:

Сервер на Ubuntu 16.04 с некоторыми характеристиками железа,
tomcat8 и проекты, работающие на нём. Есть один проект, который получает запросы извне, и на этом, в основном, строится его работа. В пиковую нагрузку (на данный момент) приходит до нескольких десятков тысяч запросов за вечер, что в среднем до 5 запросов в секунду. При такой нагрузке сервер начинает тупить - все остальные проекты тоже не отвечают. Я сам делаю любой запрос на любой из проектов, и получаю `connection timed out`.

## Что мне нужно:

стабильная работа и малая требовательность к железу.

Была (до вынужденного улучшения) примерно следующая конфигурация сервера: `Intel Xeon 2,4 ГГц` одно ядро, `1GB RAM`, остальное не так важно. Если отключить tomcat, свободной оперативной памяти было до 900 мегабайт, при даже небольшой нагрузке и включенном томкате - не более 100 мегабайт. Довольно многовато он кушает, пусть даже, возможно, мой код и не очень хорошо оптимизирован.

## Вопрос:

Какую технологию лучше использовать, на что лучше перейти, чтобы не нужны были слишком мощный сервер, и чтобы не волноваться, что при небольшом увеличении нагрузки, опять что-то может упасть.

`python`, `node.js`, какие-то фреймворки `java`, `php`, etc? Суть, в принципе, в том, чтобы перенести лишь один проект на другую платформу, и вернуться на более слабый и дешёвый сервер. Буду рад, если подскажете, в чём, возможно, проблема такой высокой требовательности томката/проекта, и на что лучше перейти. Слышал, что node.js довольно быстр, и, вроде как, быстрее всего для бэкенда. Но я не уверен, и хотел бы услышать какое-нибудь "экспертное мнение".

Если кто-то захочет сказать, что "вопрос слишком общий", и так далее, и тому подобное. **Крайне кратко конкретизирую:** сильно ли плох томкат, или может быть, причина в другом?

С помощью какой технологии на данный момент лучше всего писать приложения в бэкенд, в плане производительности и требовательности к железу?

Буду крайне благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Очевидно, ассемблер. Только прежде чем бежать на другое решение (хоть ассемблер, хоть питон, хоть нода), следует сперва тщательно разобраться в причинах проблем, иначе на другом решении вы рискуете получить те же проблемы.

Comment: @andreymal пожалуй, за асм я точно не сяду :) Причины проблем, честно говоря, не знаю как выяснить: ошибок о нехватке оперативки я не видел, точнее вообще ошибок не видел - просто время ожидания превышается.

Comment: Дебаггер в руки и смотрите, как выполняется ваш код, строчка за строчкой (правда, я не в курсе как это делается в томкате)

Comment: @andreymal к сожалению, отладка не так-то просто проводится, да и в каких условиях её проводить? Имитировать большую нагрузку и поднимать локально? Не очень понятно. Да и, по сути, там всё из коробки - я поднял томкат, создал сервлет, подписав одну аннотацию и переопределив один метод. Строчки кода бизнес-логики не такие длинные, поэтому оптимизацию кода я тоже отвергаю: перестаёт отвечать сервер полностью, и случается это лишь при большом кол-ве запросов на мой сервер. Вот с этим и нужно разобраться.

Comment: Короткие строчки обычно медленнее длинных, а всё остальное как вы описали: имитировать нагрузку, смотреть на бизнес-логику, мучаться, страдать, вот это вот всё) Я так недавно утечку памяти в python-проекте искал, через три месяца таки нашёл)

Comment: @andreymal не очень длинные, я подразумевал, что бизнес-логики в проекте не так много, и 10 строк кода особо не оптимизируешь :) Да и отлаживать лень, если честно, проще с нуля написать, я не думаю что много времени затрачу на ковыряние нода/go/питона, тем более что опыта немного уже есть, но и лишним это не будет. В общем, хотел бы узнать от знающих людей (я не очень хочу глубоко в бэкенд лезть) - вдруг есть открытая и доказанная позиция, объясняющая, на чём бэкенд быстрее всего?